# jQuery UI Sortable odd results

Tags: jquery, list, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I've spent several hours on this and scoured google and SO looking for solutions, but I cannot seem to figure out what's wrong with this code.

I would have posted the code here, but it would be messy. The source of the data is coming from an ajax call using getJSON.

```
$.getJSON('/admin/ajax_get_avail_roles/' + index, function(data2) {

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CSDVU/

Could someone please examine the working example on jsFiddle and kindly tell me how come there seems to be commas showing up in my sortable list?

Many thanks in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comma is being placed by `items.join()` try changing it to `items.join("")`

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5Zh8M/)**

[From Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join#Parameters)

> separator :
>   Specifies a string to separate each element of the array. The separator is converted to a string if necessary. If omitted, the array elements are separated with a comma.

Comment: Thank you very much! That certainly appears to have fixed the issue. I greatly appreciate both your answer and the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your [`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/CSDVU/2/), just added  `items.join('')`